# Oracle stored procedure, catch an error Errno=32152

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

My store procedure is the following:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE           "FIND_AND_DOSOMETHING" 
(
IN_PARAM1 IN MYTABLE.PARAM1_ID%TYPE,
IN_PARAM2 IN MYTABLE.PARAM2_ID%TYPE,
OUT_PARAM OUT MYTABLE.OUT_DB_ID%TYPE
)
AS 
BEGIN

  UPDATE 
  MYTABLE SET FLAG=1, PARAM1_ID=IN_PARAM1 ,TIMESTAMP = (TO_TIMESTAMP(LOCALTIMESTAMP, 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF PM'))
  WHERE OUT_DB_ID  = (SELECT OUT_DB_ID FROM MYTABLE WHERE PARAM2_ID=IN_PARAM2 AND FLAG=0 AND ROWNUM = 1)
  AND FLAG=0 RETURNING OUT_DB_ID INTO OUT_PARAM;

  -- COMMIT OUTSIDE

END FIND_AND_DOSOMETHING;
```

Works well in principle, except one case: If the nested select statement "returns zero rows" the caller gets back **"[Errno=32152,OraMsg=ORA-32152: Cannot perform operation on a null number]**"

I guess that this is due to the fact that the select statement does not return rows WHERE OUT_DB_ID = null is not valid.

One way is to catch the exception 32152 in the application code, however I was wondering if this can be done in the procedure somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a big topic, a simple Google search will find you many answers. Check out https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/errors.htm#i3372

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "FIND_AND_DOSOMETHING" (
    in_param1   IN     mytable.param1_id%TYPE
  , in_param2   IN     mytable.param2_id%TYPE
  , out_param      OUT mytable.out_db_id%TYPE
)
AS
    cannot_perform_operation   EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (cannot_perform_operation, -32152);
BEGIN
       UPDATE mytable
          SET flag = 1, param1_id = in_param1, timestamp = (TO_TIMESTAMP (LOCALTIMESTAMP, 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF PM'))
        WHERE out_db_id = (SELECT out_db_id
                             FROM mytable
                            WHERE param2_id = in_param2
                              AND flag = 0
                              AND ROWNUM = 1)
          AND flag = 0
    RETURNING out_db_id
         INTO out_param;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN cannot_perform_operation
    THEN
    -- your error processing code goes here
        NULL;
END find_and_dosomething;
```